# XSLT: How to find the last space of TEXT but not the comment preceded by 'sup' tag

Tags: xslt

XSLT: How to find the last space of TEXT but not the comment preceded by 'sup' tag

Hi, My xslt code is inserting  even after the comment text also. How to avoid this. With my coding I am getting three  tags in first para, requirement is bk should be at 'Profiling (REP'. Please suggest.

XML:

```
    <article>
   <para>Entiostats <!--td:require-hands --><!--ti-->require hands <!--/ti-->on work. This shows that Real-time Electrochemical Profiling (REP<sup>1</sup>).</para>
   <para>Entiostats require hands <!--/ti-->on work. This shows that Real-time Electrochemical Profiling (REP<sup>1</sup>).</para>
   <para>Entiostats require hands on work. This shows that Real-time Electrochemical Profiling (REP<sup>1</sup>).</para>
</article>
```

XSLT:

```
    <?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="text()[following-sibling::*[1][name()='sup' or name()='inf']][not(parent::cross-ref) and not(parent::cross-refs)]">
      <xsl:variable name="varTextBeforeSUP">
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:variable>
         <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($varTextBeforeSUP,' ')">
               <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="position()=last()">
                     <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;</xsl:text>?bk1?<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                     <xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
               </xsl:choose>
         </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Required Out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><article>
<para>Entiostats <!--td:require-hands --><!--ti-->require hands <!--/ti-->on work. This shows that Real-time Electrochemical Profiling <?bk1?>(REP<sup>1</sup>).</para>
<para>Entiostats require hands <!--/ti-->on work. This shows that Real-time Electrochemical Profiling <?bk1?>(REP<sup>1</sup>).</para>
<para>Entiostats require hands on work. This shows that Real-time Electrochemical Profiling <?bk1?>(REP<sup>1</sup>).</para>
</article>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. The problem is with this part of the expression...

```
<xsl:template match="text()[following-sibling::*[1][name()='sup' ...
```

This is matching text where the first following element is a **sup**, but that does not meant it is the most immediate sibling. Doing `*` will ignore text (or comment) nodes that might come first

Try this instead:

```
<xsl:template match="text()[following-sibling::node()[1][name()='sup' ...
```

As an aside, if you want to output `<?bk1?>`, then instead of doing this...

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;</xsl:text>?bk1?<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
```

Do this instead:

```
<xsl:processing-instruction name="bk1" />
```

Comment: Perfect sir. Thanks for the suggestion. It working as required.